# Storing the query as a column in a table and processing the output of the query into another table

Tags: sql, database, plsql, cursor

I need to basically automate this scenario.
1- I have a table STATS_QUERIES  which looks like this:
   [STATS_QUERIES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieFB1.jpg)

2-I have an output table, where I have to store the results (by referencing the former table). It looks like this: 
 [STATS_RESULTS_CARD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozJtL.jpg)

3- PL/SQL Logic: 

```
For each row in STATS_QUERIES
•   If the object type for the current query is Card:
o        Execute the query in the current row and store the results in STATS_RESULTS_CARD
•   Else if the object type of the current query is Node:
o   …
•   And so on.
   End Loop
   Commit.
```

How do I execute the row one by one from the table (target is to run the query which is stored in the STATS_QUERIES Table) and store in STATS_RESULT_CARD.

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: The links to the images are provided.

Comment: I think what you want to do is create a Stored Procedure, but you lost me with your logic.

Comment: @DaveKelly, Which part of the logic, you could not understand. Definitely, I want to create a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test
AS
   TYPE t_c IS REF CURSOR;

   c     t_c;
   s     VARCHAR2 (4000);
   src   STATS_RESULT_CARD%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
   FOR c1 IN (SELECT *
                FROM stats_queries)
   LOOP
      IF c1.object = 'Card' THEN
         OPEN c FOR c1.query;

         FETCH c INTO src;

         CLOSE c;

         INSERT INTO STATS_RESULT_CARD
              VALUES src;
      ELSE
         -- other code here
         NULL;
      END IF;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

You should have STATDATE in the queries or you can use record instead of STATS_RESULT_CARD%ROWTYPE and then on insert use field names